# Copy or Link the Chatter Post Files into Library

Tags: chatter, content, libraries

I was wondering, is there any way to link the `Chatter Post File` into a specific `Library` and make it published?

Comment: "Salesforce Content" (which I believe was renamed to Libraries) is very poorly integrated with core Salesforce. Lots of javascript, calling external servers... I'm not aware of any API calls possibility you could use. Happy to be proven otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

After you created a Feed on Chatter with a file attached, you get an object of the type [FeedItem with Type="ContentPost"](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm).
There is another field which is called "RelatedRecordId" and points to a record of type "[ContentVersion](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)". This is a version of the file that is stored in Salesforce.

If you would like to share this document afterwards with other users, groups or even libraries, you need to create additional records of the type "[ContentDocumentLink](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)", and point the field "ContentDocumentId" towards the "ContentDocumentId" of the related ContentVersion from your FeedItem and "LinkedEntityId" towards the content library. See the link for further fields and options.

Comment: I just tried this, and it looks like you cannot create `ContentDocumentLink` records using Apex or the API. If you try, you'll end up with the following error: **FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You cannot create a link for this type of entity through the api: [LinkedEntityId]**

Comment: This is a rather old post to reappear in 2017. I believe `ContentDocumentLink` has evolved considerably in 5 years and now there should be no problem doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Why yes you can! The file information is stored in the `FeedItem` object where `Type = ContentFile`.

You can query something like this:

```
SELECT ContentData,ContentDescription,ContentFileName,ContentSize,ContentType FROM FeedItem WHERE Type = 'ContentPost'
```

Note that any query involving binary data (ContentData) can only be queried one row at a time, so you will need to know the specific post you are looking for when you query.

Also note that there is no "God Mode" when it comes to Chatter / Content files, so if you don't have view access to the file, you will never be able to access it, even if you are admin.

Then you can transfer that information to a `ContentDocument` and `ContentVersion` object for the file itself, and the ContentWorkspace and ContentWorkspaceDoc object for the library connection.

Check out the documentation on those objects here for help:

- [Object Reference for Salesforce and Lightning Platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm)